# Is there any implementation of JVM that supports CUDA?

Tags: java, jvm, cuda

Is there any implementation of JVM that supports CUDA? Provide links please =)

Comment: Compile to CUDA code, or just talk to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [JCuda](http://www.jcuda.de/jcuda/JCuda.html):

> With JCuda it is possible to interact with the CUDA runtime and driver API from Java programs.

Comment: JCuda is very nice. But I see spaceships in eternal void desserts of univers that is full of programers who do not need to care about external cuda api, and can use the power of GPU like we use the power of  mulicore CPU.